# Compiling exploit on a different kernel than target (but same arch): is it un-smart or risky?

Tags: exploit, exploit-development

I'm in a situation where I've compiled about 15 or more exploits for a machine and each has failed. The failures had to do with the kernel being compiled with highly secure settings, i.e. mmap function being disabled, or ptrace function. Only one of the errors was an unexplained segfault. Both machines are x86 so it's not as if I'm cross compiling for a different arch.

Is it truly worth it for me to recompile all of these failing exploits on a VM matching the kernel of the target machine if none of the errors (save for the nebulous segfault) seem related to compilation/compatibility issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It does not matter what kernel you compile an exploit under.**

The failures were because the kernel was providing protections from the exploit methods you used. These protections are done at runtime. The kernel does not somehow insert code to cripple exploits compiled under it. The solution would be to *run* the exploit on a kernel with these security features removed or disabled, not to *compile* it on such a kernel. You do not have to have ASLR running (or even supported by your kernel) to compile a position-independent executable, for example.

The running kernel does not change the output of the compiler in a way that would break an exploit. All that matters is that you are compiling it with the same (or at least compatible) compiler features, libraries (if statically linked), and optimizations. If this is the case, it can be compiled anywhere. You could even compile an exploit for a Linux application on Windows or OpenBSD, and vice versa.

Some things you may want to keep in mind regarding your toolchain's environment:

- Compiling on one system with `-march=native` may result in an executable that does not function properly or at all on another system. Avoid hardware-specific optimizations.
- Using features from, say, GCC 7.2.0 may cause breakage if compiled on a machine that only has 6.4.0. The same applies to regressions that may break an exploit on a newer compiler.
- If your target has header files which are incompatible with a working exploit for whatever reason, you will need to include the correct header files or compile it under a system which has them.
- Some libraries' build systems check the kernel version running, and use this to decide what features to include. Be aware of this if you are compiling libraries on this system as well.